# query sql select twice in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I must select in same table two `project.project_dates` (one for start and one for end) in the table I've two fields `project.start = true` and `project.end = true` for identify it

What should the SQL query look like?

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    pz.cognome AS Cognome,
    (select s.presa_in_carico_data from tbl_progetto s where s.is_progetto = 1 AND                    
        s.cc_id_fk = cc.cc_id) as Start,
    (select e.presa_in_carico_data from tbl_progetto e where e.is_dimissione = 1 AND 
        e.cc_id_fk = cc.cc_id) as End, 
    trf.trf_note AS "Tipo trattam.",
    trf.trf_prezzou as Retta,
    COUNT(tra.trt_id) AS "N.GG." /*<-- this is normal count from date range select from user(#) */
FROM
    tbl_progetto p 
    JOIN tbl_cartellaclinica cc ON cc.cc_id = p.cc_id_fk
    JOIN tbl_paziente pz ON pz.id = cc.pz_fk_id
    JOIN tbl_distretti_sanitari di ON pz.distretto_appartenenza = di.dss_id
    JOIN tbl_trattamenti tra ON p.pr_id = tra.pr_fk_id    
WHERE
    tra.trt_data BETWEEN '2012-08-01' AND '2012-08-31' AND
    p.pr_faseriab_fk = 4
GROUP BY cc_id
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: 1. You need to provide more details to get a meaningful answer. 2. You should show what you have tried.

Comment: Table schema, example data, expected results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.id as ProjectId,
(select s.date from project_dates s where s.start = true and s.project_id = p.id) as StartDate,
(select e.date from project_dates e where e.end = true and e.project_id = p.id) as EndDate
into #temp
from Project p
```

Update:

To answer your comment, again I have to make assumptions about how things look in your database, but I would do something like this:

Create a temp-table for storing the result of the above query (see changes).. Then:

```
select p.id
       (select count(1) from Meeting m where m.date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-08-31' and m.project_id = p.id) as Count1
       (select count(1) from Meeting m where m.date between (select StartDate from #temp where ProjectId = p.id) and (select EndDate from #temp where ProjectId = p.id) and m.project_id = p.id) as count2
from Project p 
[where p.id = <something>]
```

Comment: Interesting query, but are you sure that it is related with the question?

Comment: thank you very much @Tobb I had no idea how to do this, for the others because I have not posted the same scheme to not bore you with the usual unnecessary joins, and tables, my question was about how to ask twice for the same field in the same query.

Comment: now that I have a range of dates, can I ask twice the count of appointments, which ranges between 2 different dates?
eg. select count (meeting.id) from meetings m where m.date between '2012-08-01 ' and '2012-08-31' ... then another  select count (meeting.id) from meetings where m.date between StartDate and EndDate (aliases above)

Comment: Argeman: Sure I am not, the question was quite vague, but I think I understood correctly ;)

Comment: thanks @Tobb, a question, why count(1) ? what's 1 ? thanks ;) I feel just the query and will upgrade

Comment: Paste it in your original question for better readability..

The count(1) part is just an optimization, you don't actually care about any of the fields in the table to be counted, doing count(1) will give the same result as count(*)/count(id)/count(whatever), but will be faster (i think). Not very important though.. (You could also use count(null) with the same result.

Comment: Ok, will have a look at it after work :)

Comment: please staff could you remove ban from my account ? ridiculous! There are thousands and this leads others to support forum, dreamers.